# Laravel SearchByKeyword Scope for Relation?

Tags: laravel, scope, relation

I've found this function on Stackoverflow. It allows to define a keyword, and the function checks if it is part of different columns in my database.

```
 public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword)
    {
        if ($keyword != '') {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                $query->where("reference", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                    ->orWhere("description", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");
            });
        }
        return $query;
    }
```

Now, I want to add a `->orWhere()` to search for a village. However in my Model is only a field called `village_id` which is in a relationship to my `villages`-table.

So if I would do `->orWhere("village_id", "LIKE", "%$keyword%");` it would search in a columns only containing id's. How can I tell the Scope it should search inside of `<RelationName> -> name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`orWhereHas`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_orWhereHas) like this:

```
public function scopeSearchByKeyword($query, $keyword)
{
    if ($keyword != '') {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where("reference", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere("description", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhereHas('villages', function($q) use($keyword) {
                    $q->where('column_name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%"); // <----- Do your stuff here.
                });
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but i cant use $keyword inside of `$q->where()` appearently. Any idea?

Comment: Just use - `use ($keyword)` into closure, see updated answer

Comment: Works great! Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to see, that it helped you! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`orWhereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) methods to put `where` conditions on your `has` queries. This method allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a village as:

```
->orWhereHas('villages', function($q) use($keyword) {
    $q->where("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
});
```

So your final query will be as:

```
$query->where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
    $query->where("reference", "LIKE","%$keyword%")
        ->orWhere("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
        ->orWhere("description", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
        ->orWhereHas('villages', function($q) use($keyword) {
            $q->where("title", "LIKE", "%$keyword%")
        });
});
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)